# jenkins pipeline fail - ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add ; says error loading key - invalid format

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-pipeline, private-key, ssh-agent

I'm trying to ssh into ec2 from jenkins, i have set the credentials in jenkins global with key downloaded from aws i,e "something.pem" . I copied the contents and pasted. not sure why jenkins is not able to read from the private key

```
`SSH_AGENT_PID=2612
Running ssh-add (command line suppressed)
Error loading key "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/ultibranch-pipeline_jenkins-           
jobs@tmp/private_key_8683577244018302829.key": invalid format
[Pipeline] // sshagent
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Failed to run ssh-add
Finished: FAILURE`
```

i looked for solution but mostly they say its because of a line break at the end of the RSA private key line, i did add a line break and ran the pipeline but it fails eventually

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with key format. EC2 gives PEM-formatted keys, and ssh currently uses different format ([lengthy explanation here](https://superuser.com/questions/1720991/differences-between-begin-rsa-private-key-and-begin-openssh-private-key)). You can see the difference in the header, PEM file uses

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and ssh keys

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

There are ways to convert the keys back and forth, but by far the easiest way is to try to generate a new key:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa
```

Then try to import that key to Jenkins (copy paste generated `~/.ssh/id_rsa` contents). If that succeeds, log in to the destination EC2 hosts and append the line from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.